# How can I get a List of subelements from a subdictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I want to get a list of subelements from a subdictionary

I have this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<InstanceLog>>> dic;
```

And I want something like this (Fetch all InstanceLog-Lists from the subdictinary in one big list.):

```
List<InstanceLog> logList = GetValues(dic);
```

I have tried something like this but it don't work:

```
List<InstanceLog> logList = GetFetchtedList()
  .Select(x => x.Value.ToList())
  .Cast<InstanceLog>()
  .ToList()
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Try selectmany()

Comment: @the.Doc Thanks for your tipp puts its not working. I'm getting this:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.InstanceLog]]' to type 'Models. InstanceLog.'

Comment: Out of interest, why the `Cast`?

Comment: Could you check my answer? didn't it work for you? I write it on the fly and tried to make as simple as possible in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *flatten* `dic` *twice*:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<InstanceLog>>> dic = ...;

List<InstanceLog> logList = dic
  .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value) // Inner Dictionaries
  .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value) // Inner Lists
  .ToList();                      // Materialized as one big list
```

Comment: You don't have to flatten twice. This means you iterate the collection twice. you can do it once.

Comment: @Franck: sure we don't have to iterate over any (sub-)collection more than once. I mean we have to apply faltten operation - `SelectMany` - twice. Sorry for my words choice and possible mess

Answer (score 2):

In technical language, you want to **flatten** the lists which are stored inside the values of dictionary, so you need `SelectMany`:

```
var values = dic.Values
                 .SelectMany(val => val.Values)
                 .SelectMany(val => val);
```

where `values` will be a collectopn of your data of type `IEnumerable<InstanceLog>` which is exactly what you want.

Comment: This is not what he "exactly wants" you return a `KeyValuePair<string,List<InstanceLog>>` and not a `List<InstanceLog>`

Answer (score 0):

`SelectMany` is the keyword. What it does is group as one list if the select is an collection of some sort. If you like it return like you would do `Union`.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<InstanceLog>>> dic;

var instanceLogs = dic.SelectMany(d => d.Value.Select(subd => subd.Value)).ToList();
```

The `SelectMany` on `dic` tell linq :

"Hey i will have a collection result within those parenthesis so group them as 1 collection"

The `Select` on the sub dictionary just return the collection 1 for the `SelectMany` to grab and process.

This iterate the collection **only once** and does not use any extra operations that is not needed (linq wise)